# What is good practice for installing code that will be JIT compiled?

Tags: cuda, installation, cmake, opencl, jit

When designing the installation of a Unix-style command-line application, if there is code that will be just-in-time (JIT) compiled, is there a standard or best practice for the location in the install tree to which the source (and headers) should be installed? Is `${root}/share/${appname}/src` reasonable?

The particular context is a mixed C/C++ application configured with CMake that builds with at most one of CUDA or OpenCL support (which might use JIT), but I don't think any of this matters for the answer.

Clearly one cannot rely on the copy of the source files that is in the source or build tree, since these will not necessarily be present (or findable) at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the OpenCL kernel code, modify your build system to embed the code into headers as strings. Use the strings directly to pass into your OpenCL runtime. There's no need, and little reason, to keep the OpenCL kernels in separate files. You could use the preprocessor to turn a .cl file into a header, or better just write a quick python script to do it.

I imagine that similar approaches would work for other systems. Either there would be a standard location or environment variable (c.f. CLASSPATH in Java) or you would want to embed them directly into the installed binary.

Comment: Using the build system to embed the code into the library or executable does indeed seem like a good idea. Preprocessing them into strings embedded into the compiled source and later passed to the JIT compiler seems to me to be a better approach than preprocessing them into installed(?) headers.

Comment: I meant into a header that you include in the source, just for cleaner code. so blah.cl becomes const char * blah = "..."; in foo.h, and your C or C++ sources include foo.h. That way you generate a new file and include it with the preprocessor rather than trying to update a preexisting file.